# Dash/Flask - Deployment of an application on my own server

Tags: python, web, deployment, server, plotly-dash

I am a newbie in web development, I am an energy engineering student trying to make a project, so I apologize if I say something weird.

I've made an application using Dash (python). And now, I would like to deploy that app in my server. I have a remote server (debian, adress.com, IP, opened ports: 80 and 443...) with my ssh public key and all the required stuff.

I have read all the official documentation in the plotly dash page, and also in flask's, but I dont understand very well the thing. I need either Heroku, OpenShift... And I dont understand very well how them work.

Could you please recommend me an easy tutorial (for dummies!) or give me advices/examples about the deployment? I would really apreciate I've searched the Internet a lot, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You describe two options: 
1. using your own server to host your app and 
2. using a service which will host your app (heroku, etc.)

1. **Using your own server to host your app**

   You need to decide for a web server, which is serving your page on your server. A host will not magically answer on any port. There is for example apache, nginx, etc... After having chosen one, you need to find a tutorial: how to run your flask app  on [yourwebserver] or something like that.

   Suppose you have chosen apache, you will find something like this:
   https://jackhalpinblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/27/getting-your-python-3-flask-app-to-run-on-apache/
   (In this case, you will have to figure out how to run your flask app with python3 instead of python2, if you are running debian)

   When your page serves your page, you need an ssl certificate in order to make use of your domain. An easy way of doing this is https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/ (there are probably other similar services)
2. **Using a service, which will host your app for you (heroku, etc.)**

   Alternatively do not host you app on your own server, but on heroku, aws, gcd, etc., in my opinion this is much easier than hosting it on your own server. The documentation on hosting service websites is normally very good.

   For heroku a good starting point would be here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python. Nevertheless the other services are easy to use as well, i just use this as an example.